# Can't access computer because keyboard doesn't work in GRUB

Tags: boot, grub2, keyboard

I just used mainline to install the latest kernel on Ubuntu 22.10 on an HP Envy x360. I rebooted, and now it's stuck at GRUB because I can't do anything with the keyboard. I can't boot from a USB either.

When I start up, it shows these screens and gets stuck at the last one. Please help, I literally just bought this computer.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Edit: OK, I was able to get into my computer by using an external keyboard and am now installing Ubuntu 22.04. Still curious why the internal keyboard didn't work.

Edit2: And I realize now that the internal keyboard never worked in the boot menu from the first time I went to install Ubuntu and even now. I've been using the touch screen. But for the above screen, the touch screen was not working either.

The boot menu automatically starts with onscreen touch buttons for the required F and arrow keys, so maybe HP knows the keyboard doesn't work.

Comment: If you can't boot from a USB, it is not related to Ubuntu.

Comment: If you can not use external keyboard may be your usb legancy has been disabled in bios settings

Comment: Grub does not have drivers for keyboard, it relies on UEFI/BIOS. You may have a setting in UEFI for USB boot, or full USB support. Or even a separate setting for USB keyboard & mouse enablement.

Answer (score 1):

You installed an unsigned mainline kernel with enabled Secure Boot. That's why it is not booting.

You should be able to boot from a LiveUSB. It is not related to the installed OS.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I forgot that I had read about disabling Secure Boot.